# First code in Spark (python)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to Spark and trying to create something simple.
I have a file with 2 columns: dates and values.
For every 6th date I'd like to give a projection based on the previous 5 values using linear regression.
Then write it out to a file and also the error between the real values and the projected ones to a 3rd column.

So far I have this:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from datetime import datetime
from timeit import timeit

def after(line, date):
  current = line.split(';')[0]
  currentDate = datetime.strptime(current, '%Y.%m.%d')
  if currentDate > datetime.strptime(date, '%Y.%m.%d'):
    return True
  else:
    return False

def getValue(line):
  return float(line.split(';')[1])

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

data = sc.textFile('./AAPL.csv')

average = latest_data.reduce(lambda l1, l2: l1+l2)/latest_data.count()

printed_data = data.filter(lambda line: after(line, u'2015.03.27')).map(lambda d: [getValue(d), average, (getValue(d)-average)*(getValue(d)-average)])

printed_data.saveAsTextFile('./result.txt')
```

My problem is I don't know how to create for-loop kind of stuff in Spark. I mean if I have, say, 10 computers to work on this, I want the calculations to run in parallel...

And as a next step I only want to get the sum of the errors in the result.txt file. (Only this one number.)

Comment: If you want to do something simple, I recommend you change the problem. The difficulty comes from working on batches of 6 consecutive lines. `sc.textFile` is line-based. It's very likely that some batches will be spread across different partitions, different machines (if you have more than one). You can probably see the problem with that.

Comment: @DanielDarabos I think you could flatMap into a key/value: key(index of row), value(date/value). Then group the pairings by /6 for each whole number (first 6 until you get 6/6=1, 12/6=2, etc). Then do your calculations, which would be more distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Check sc.parallelize see if that's what you want.

After

```
data = sc.textFile('./AAPL.csv')
```

You might want to do something like

```
distData = sc.parallelize(data)
```

or

```
distDAta = sc.parallelize(data, 10)  // say you want to split those 10 piece and run it ( regardless how your environment actually can though... )
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're interested to get it computed in parallel by using spark. Thus it's important to get every element in RDD independent to each other. It's important to get every six row/records into one element. As theMadKing pointed out, **There's no need to use any loop because the order of RDD is guaranteed** except certain functions. I personally prefer to use RDD index instead of #range().

The following are pseudocode to transform read RDD into such calculation. Basically, 1)create week# and used it as the aggregation keys for later aggregation 2)do linear regression of values from single element of RDD.

First read the file, you need to write your own parser function to split each line of the csv to the tuple of date and value. And use zipWithIndex() to get line number.

```
lineIndexRDD = sc.textFile('./AAPL.csv').map(parser).zipWithIndex()
# lineIndexRDD is now (date, value, line#)
```

Next, map the line# to week#, so every 6 lines would have the same week number by line number devided by 6, and this week number can be used to aggregate.

```
weekRDD = lineIndexRDD.map(lambda (date, value, lineNum):(lineNum/6, (date, value))).groupByKey()
# weekIndexRDD is now (week#, [(date1, value1),(date2, value2),...(date6, value6)])
```

Now you can do linear regression because every element of RDD, you need to write your own linear regression function to calculate the values in the input array and return prediction and error.

```
lrRDD = weekRDD.map(myLinearRegression)
#your LinearRegression function should take a tuple of (week#, 6daysRecordsArray) and output a tuple of (week#, prediction, error, 6daysRecordsArray)
# lrRDD is now (week#, prediction, error, [(date1, value1),(date2, value2),...(date6, value6)])
```

Finally you can reformat the RDD to the final format you want and write it down, it's very wordy below, but you can write a helper function for it. I'm not sure about what you want at the 6th date so please double check it.

```
finalRDD = lrRDD
.flatMap(lambda(weekNum, prediction, error, [(d1, v1),(d2, v2),...(d6, v6)]):(d1, v1),(d2, v2),...(d5, v5),(d6, v6, prediction, error)
).saveAsTextFile(outputFile.name)
#don't forget to insert newline (\n) in between!
```